# Return repeated groups only if above a certain number

Tags: regex, logging, match

I'm setting up a regex to look for null pointer exceptions in logs. The regex for this is very simple:

```
(java\.lang\.NullPointerException)
```

And this returns three groups from my logs:

```
2020-01-31 00:00:01 - Searching for account details
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
2020-01-31 00:00:30 - Searching for account details
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
2020-01-31 00:00:50 - Searching for account details
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What I would like to do is set this up to only return results if there is more than a certain number of matching groups.  For example, (java.lang.NullPointerException){2,} should in theory return results for two or more groups, while {4,} should not match.  So far, I've been reading up on using curly brackets for this, but I have not been able to get this to work with anything other than {1,} - everything else just returns no matches.

EDIT:
Thanks to Pavel for the answer.  I made a slight modification for my use case:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s-\sSearching\sfor\saccount\sdetails\nError:\njava\.lang\.NullPointerException[\s\S]){10,}
```

This pattern is to match exactly that message from the date to the null pointer error.  I also removed the `*` from `[\s\S]`, to ensure that it only catches 10 consecutive errors.  That way, if there is 10 or more instances of:

```
2020-01-31 00:00:01 - Searching for account details
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

it will return a match.  But if there is something like:

```
2020-01-31 00:00:50 - Searching for account details
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
2020-01-31 00:00:50 - Searching for account details
Found something:
Hello world
2020-01-31 00:00:50 - Searching for account details
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

A match will not be returned, due to the `hello world` message between the messages.  I did not think of this use case until after the fact, so I didn't include it in the original question.

Comment: You need to make a multi-line search. I'm assuming you're using Java?

Comment: Are the same type of exceptions in sequence, so no other types in between?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you describe it:

```
(java\.lang\.NullPointerException[\s\S]*){2,}
```

See, you need to add [\s\S]* to the end so that it matches all the characters between the two exceptions including whitespaces.

Here's the demo: https://regex101.com/r/dnIgKs/1/

Comment: Depending on the interpreter, this may also need a multi-line modifier, such as `m` or `s` or `ms`. Some interpreters will need to be told to change their definition of a "line" (e.g. by changing the record separator to null, [search for slurp](https://duckduckgo.com/?ia=software&q=slurp+file)), though note you'd possibly need the `m` flag and to start the parenthesized section with `^`. Otherwise, I recommend `\b` at the beginning of the parenthesized portion for some speedup.

Comment: @AdamKatz agreed, I have the "m" flag there in the demo

Comment: This seems to work for my use case.  In my case, I also decided to delete the * at the end to ensure that if any other message breaks the trend before there are 10 instances, the regex will ignore that group.  I'll update my question to show that.